# Compact operator with continuous inverse

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $K:E \rightarrow E$ be a compact operator on a normed space $E$. Let $R^q$ be the range of $(\lambda I-K)^q$ where $q$ is such that $R^n = R^q$ for all $n \geq q$. Also, the restriction $(\lambda I - K)|_{R^q}$ has an inverse. Prove that the inverse of this restriction $(\lambda I-K)|_{R^q}^{-1}$ is continuous.

Since these are linear operators, continuous is equivalent to bounded. So, $(\lambda I -K)$ is continuous (because $K$ is compact), then bounded. Hence, there's a $C > 0$ such that $||(\lambda I - K)x|| \leq C ||x||$. The only hint I have is that I've to prove that there's a $C_2>0$ such that $$||(\lambda I - K)x|| \geq C_2 ||x||.$$ But I don't see why this proves the statement. Since I'm working with the restriction to $R^q$, $x \in R^q$ so $(\lambda I -K)x = (\lambda I -K)(\lambda I -K)^q y$ for some $y \in E$. But since $R^q = R^{q+1}$, $(\lambda I -K)x = (\lambda I -K)^q z$ for some $z \in E$. And now I'm stuck. Then, I tried to write $x = (\lambda I-K)^{-1}[(\lambda I-K)x]$ but I didn't get anything. Any hint? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose $\lambda$ is assumed to be nonzero, correct?  If so, $\lambda I-K$ is a Fredholm operator on $R^q$ whose index
is zero.  Since the index of a Fredholm operator $T$ is defined by
$$\text{ind}(T)= \text{dim}(\text{Ker}(T)) - \text{codim}(\text{Ran}(T)), $$
and since
$\lambda I-K$ is onto $R^q$ by the assumption that $R^q=R^{q+1}$, we deduce that
$\lambda I-K$ is one-to-one, and hence invertible on $R^q$.

It is also well known that the range of a Fredholm operator is always closed, so $R^q$ is closed, and hence a Banach
space.  Finally, since $\lambda I-K$ is invertible on $R^q$,  the open mapping Theorem implies that
$(\lambda I-K)^{-1}$ is continuous on $R^q$.

---

PS: I realize that there might be some rather sophisticated results being used here, so please do not hesitate to ask if you'd
like me to be more explicit with any of the above statements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, I didn't understand anything, sorry. I'm looking at Riesz theory in this course. We've proved that $\text{ker}(\lambda I - K)$ is finite dimensional and $\text{ran}(\lambda I -K)$ is closed. We also proved that the restriction of $\lambda I- K$ to $R^q$ is invertible. In order to prove that the inverse is continuous, I've to find a $c > 0$ such that $||(\lambda I - K)x|| \geq c ||x||$. Not only I can't do this, but I don't see why this proves the statement that $(\lambda I -K)^{-1}$ is bounded (I don't know the open mapping theorem)

Comment: OK, so here is a hint for an elementary proof, beginning with the proof of the existence of $C_2$. If $C_2$ does not exist
then, for each $n$, there is some $x_n$ in $R^q$ such that $\|(\lambda I-K)x_n\|< (1/n)\|x_n\|$.  Assuming WLOG that
$\|x_n\|=1$, notice that since $K$ is compact,  there is a converging subsequence $\{K(x_{n_k})\}_k$.  Can you now
prove that $\{\lambda x_{n_k}\}_k$ converges?

Comment: Yes, what would be the next step?

Comment: If $y=\lim _nx_n$, what is $(\lambda I-K)(y)$?

Comment: $(\lambda I - K)y = 0$??

Comment: Yep! This contradicts the fact that $\lambda I-K$ is invertible so some assumption we made above is incorrect.  What is it?

Comment: The assumption that such $C_2$ does not exist. How do we know that $y \neq 0$ and how the existence of such $C_2$ proves that $(\lambda I - K)^{-1}$ is continuous?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115402/discussion-between-ruy-and-ejrionm).